# What is the best practice to return login credentials in a rest API response?

Tags: java, web-services, api, rest, security

In a user registration API if i need to register same user on other third parties servers like Wowza, open-fire. When register on third party servers we create password using some algorithms, in that case need to return login credentials in API response so client side directly user there API's.

According to me:

1. Return credentials in API response.
2. Registration on third parties servers part move to client side.

Please suggest which one I need to follow.

If any one have batter solution then please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding(strictly my point of view) returning  credentials like password etc either in encrypted or plain text to client side is not at all expected.
If need to register on third party domain we may use OAuth like framework which would do the job for the manual client side rendering